# Getting value of input field in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, alert

My HTML:

```js
var searchInput = $("#searchField").val()
$("#searchButton").on("click", function() {
  alert(searchInput)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="searchField">
<button type="submit" id="searchButton">Submit</button>
```

With this code, after I click the "Submit" button, I only get an **empty** alert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining the `searchInput` before any value is set..

Try this:

```
$("#searchButton").on("click", function() {
    var searchInput = $("#searchField").val()
    alert(searchInput)               
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/110276/

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the value inside the click handler:

```
$("#searchButton").on("click", function() {
       alert($("#searchField").val())               
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Bring `var searchInput = $("#searchField").val()` calculation inside the onclick event.